# Silverlight cursor position not right in Firefox

Tags: silverlight, firefox

In Firefox 4/5, my Silverlight page reports the cursor position lower than where the actual cursor is on the screen. This means that I have to position my cursor above what I want to click on, rather than actually clicking on it.

As I have been investigating more, I can confirm that it works in IE8/9, and in Safari on Mac properly. This issue vanishes in FF 4/5 if I run the browser in full screen mode.

**Edit:** This only seems to happen when I have `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled.npctrl.dll` set to `false`, keeping Silverlight out of the plugin container.

**Edit 2:** This is a Firefox bug, and seems to have been there in one form or another since they implemented Out Of Process Plugins. See this bug: [Mozilla Bug ID: 599992](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=599992). Guess I will have to wait until this is fixed.