# Silverlight printing in web browser problem

Tags: silverlight-4.0, printing

I'm trying to print from a Silverlight application.

Printing works when I run the application Out Of Browser. But when I run it in the web browser, the Print dialog is shown but nothing happens when I click the buttons (Print, Cancel, or even close the window). I tried running without debugger attached (deployed to IIS) but it's the same thing.

The code:

```
    private void PrintLabel()
    {
        PrintDocument printDocument = new PrintDocument();
        printDocument.PrintPage += new EventHandler<PrintPageEventArgs>(printDocument_PrintPage);
        printDocument.Print("Label for " + this.tbSerialNo.Text);
    }

    void printDocument_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        e.PageVisual = this.csLabel;
    }
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a browser-specific issue I have seen in the past. Are you running this in Firefox 3.6 or later? If so, [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=602502) Firefox bug might be of some interest to you since the print dialog *is* a popup window as well.

You can fix this popup issue by setting `dom.ipc.plugins.enabled` to false in Firefox's `about:settings` menu. However, this sometimes causes mouse oddities, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6458090/silverlight-cursor-position-not-right-in-firefox).

If this is the case(and it sounds like it is), printing *does* work in Out-Of-Browser mode since its really just running Silverlight in an IE process without any toolbars.

Comment: I just tried it in Chrome and there it works! There is something wrong with my Internet Explorer (9.0.8112.16421). Running on 64-bit Win 7 Pro SP 1.